# Laravel 8 - Image not deleted from storage + not updating when "Edit"

Tags: php, laravel-8

possible "duplicate": [Laravel - Delete images from storage / update post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61050900/laravel-delete-images-from-storage-update-post)

I want laravel to delete the old image and replace it with new uploaded image in the edit form. I tried doing this:

```
if( $request->hasfile('violationStatement') ) {
            $destination = 'violations/' . $violation->violationStatement;
            // Deletes the file if it exists
            if( File::exists($destination) ) {
                File::delete($destination);
            }
            $file = $request->file('violationStatement');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = time() . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('violations/', $filename);
            $violation->violationStatement = $filename;
        }

        $violation->update();
```

But the image is not deleted nor updating. In addition, I want to have a condition when I just want to edit data without uploading new image...

Here is the routing:

```
// Traffic Violations
        Route::controller(TrafficViolationController::class)->group(function () {
            Route::get('violations', 'index')->name('violations.index'); // Index page (DataTable)
            Route::get('violations/create', 'create')->name('violations.create'); // The form for adding new records
            Route::post('violations/create', 'store')->name('violations.store'); // Add new to DB
            Route::get('violations/edit/{violation}', 'edit')->name('violations.edit'); // The form for editing records
            Route::put('violations/edit/{violation}', 'update')->name('violations.update'); // Update record to DB
            Route::get('violations/{violation}', 'destroy')->name('violations.destroy'); // Delete from DB
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

- First make sure of namespace

  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
- Then edit  $violation->update() to  $violation->save();
- And if the path in public folder use this method public_path() as this

  $destination = public_path('violations/' . $violation->violationStatement);
- But if the path in storage folder use this method storage_path() as this

  $destination = storage_path('violations/' . $violation->violationStatement);

Comment: No matter what I do the file still doesn't update nor delete

Comment: After doing the edits in my answer if it still not work Try storeAs() instead of move() and edit the method in condition hasfile() to hasFile()

Comment: Thank you for your time, do you know how to debug in laravel so I can see where the issue is? Because still nothing is working...

Comment: Use this package for debug in laravel
https://laravel.io/forum/02-04-2014-package-laravel-debugbar

Answer (score 0):

I use `Intervention\Image\Facades\Image` for uploading image And `Illuminate\Support\Facades\File` For Manage Directories. below Code replace Pic If Exist. think now you have `123.jpg` and you want replace it. it replace old pic with new one. if your image name is difference you can delete old one.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

//Get Data Of uploaded pic

$file = $request->file('violationStatement');
$srcPath = $file->getRealPath();
$size = $file->getSize(); // if You Need Pic Size
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

//Start Uploading

$Image = Image::make($srcPath);
$destPath = public_path("violations");
File::ensureDirectoryExists($destPath); // Check Directory Exist Or Make 
$filename = time() . '.' . $extension;
$Image->save($destPath.'/'.$filename);
```

at last I suggest add some unique thing to Your Image Name because it may two user upload picture at Same Time!!! and One Picture replaced.